# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'There was no match for the specified key in the index. (0x80070491)'

Tags: .net, excel, file-permissions

trying to add permissions to excel file from .net core 6. Am using Microsoft.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.Office.Core libraries.
On debugging i got to know the error is in line

`workbook.Permission.Add('user@domain.com',MsoPermission.msoPermissionRead, new DateTime(2025, 12, 31))`

Note: Same code is working for few machines but for few its giving this error.

can anyone help me to get an idea, what can be the probable issues. I have checked for few possibilities but didn't got anything concrete:

- Checked for Office Version : Same for both machines
- Checked for .Net version : Same for both machines
- Checked for Access Level : Used admin access in machines having issue

As mentioned i tried adding permission with the help of Workbook.Permission.Add()
worked for few machines but not working in few machines

Comment: Quote: *Use of the Permission object raises an error when the Windows Rights Management client is not installed*

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but when i looked for this its not present on either of the machines